# link to file in sub folder

Tags: php, html

please,I am trying to create link to a php file in sub folder using  tag but when I am testing the link it gives "NOT FOUND" error this is the code `<a href="../pages/about.php">About</a>`

Comment: Did you place the file in your root folder htdocs/wamp on your local server. Php basically needs xamp or wamp to execute the files.

Comment: is the path correct? one directory behind the actual script?

Comment: Read the W3 document for href or visit W3Schools

Comment: What is the URL of the page you want it to link to? What is the URL of the page it actually links to? Don't make us guess!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that name of file or folder is correct with caps lock text. something like this in below:

```
<a href="../Pages/About.php">About</a>
```

If about.php is in pages folder and you are gonna link to another file in this folder, you must remove ../ from the code, something like this:

```
<a href="Pages/About.php">About</a>
```

Please provide link of About.php that we'll check it out, it's easy way to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Browse to the file in the browser manually, then work backwards.
- Draw a map of your directories, for visual aid

For example;

```
 .public_html/
 ..pages/
  page1.html
  ..files/
  ...config/
 ..folder1
 ..folder2/
 index.html
```

The link from index.html to pages/page1.html would be

```
<a href="pages/page1.html">Page1</a>
```

The link from pages/page1.html to index.html would be

```
<a href="../index.html">Index</a>
```